# Drupal Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal

I am attempting to achieve sliding using the effect function of Jquery UI.

Using the following code:

```
$('div#main div#sidebar-left').effect('slide');
```

gives me a function not recognised error.

**Since I have the Jquery UI module installed, I wonder if any knows how I might call my desire function via the module?**

Comment: which version of drupal are you using, 6 or 7?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this is Drupal 6, in which case you need to add the jQuery UI files to the page with `jquery_ui_add()`.

```
jquery_ui_add('effects.slide');
```

Or something very similar to that. This function will go in a page callback function, or in a `hook_init()` if you need it on every page.

Comment: Thanks Clive, apologies for the non-response to your inquiry. You were right - its a D6 site.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
jQuery('div#main div#sidebar-left').effect('slide');
```

Answer (score -1):

To include jQuery in your pages:

```
<?php
 drupal_add_js (
    '$(document).ready(function(){$("p.jtest").fadeIn(6000);}); ',
    'inline');
?>
```

( From http://drupal.org/node/89005 )

To do the slide:

We can animate any element, such as a simple image:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
```

We will cause .slideToggle() to be called when another element is clicked:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

( From the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ )